# cannot find Require.js

Tags: javascript, npm, requirejs

I have some legacy-browser-app with a few dependencies that I want to migrate to TypeScript. So I used the following within my `app.ts` and compile that against ES6 with AMD (I hope AMD is right for browser):

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as LG from 'leaflet-geosearch';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

which is compiled to the following:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

I reference that using the following HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I load that into my browser, I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

So I searched around and got to know this is most probably an error with RequireJS. Following the docs from RequireJS at https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html. I downloaded RequireJS with NPM, because I already installed the dependency for leaflet via NPM as well. Instead of referencing my `app.js` within my HTML, I now have this:

```
<head>
  <script>
    var requirejs = require('requirejs');
    requirejs.config({ nodeRequire: require });

    requirejs(['leaflet', 'scripts/app.js']);
  </script>
</head>
```

However now I get

> require is not defined

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `require` in the browser. You have include the RequireJS explicitly in the browser:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
require(['leaflet', 'scripts/app.js']);
</script>
```

This will load the RequireJS but it will probably break because paths to `leaflet` might be wrong. But I guess you can fix that :)